# Matlab: How to override intrinsic function with variable in workspace

Tags: matlab, workspace

I would like to know how to override an intrinsic function with a variable defined in the workspace in Matlab R2015a when running an m file.

I mean if I define:

```
function test
fun1
clear input
load test
plot(input)
return

function fun1
input=1:10;
save('test.mat','input')
return
```

and I run test, then I get:

```
Error using input
Not enough input arguments.

Error in test (line 8)
plot(input)
```

Matlab is taking input as its in-built function.

Do you know how to solve this (without changing the variable name)?

Thanks.

Comment: You should never overwrite a built-in function. (To avoid this kind of error)

Comment: But if you create a variable or a new .m file that as the exact same name of a built-in function, this built-in function will be "overwrite".

Comment: @obchardon I disagree. There's absolutely no problem to do so if you know what you're doing - for example when overloading operators for custom classes (`plus()` etc.). MATLAB even provides the [`builtin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html) function ("_Execute built-in function from overloaded method_") to call the original version when needed. || cardogar - it's bad practice to "spawn variables into existence" using `load`. A much better approach is `A=load(...); var = A.someName` which is less confusing both for mlint and for humans.

Comment: @obchardon if you load the variable the built-in function is not overwritten. Thanks a lot Dev-iL that easily solves my problem since I cannot change the mat file in my actual problem.

Comment: @cardogar my bad i'm using octave which overwrite the built-in functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is given in the comments by @Dev-iL

Better not to spawn variables into existence variables in the workspace.

So this would make the simple example above to work:

```
A=load('test.mat');
input=A.input
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the exact filename, include extension.
And better use variable that will accept the input.

```
function test
    fun1
    clear input
    data=load('test.mat');
    plot(data.input)
    return
end   
function fun1
    input=1:10;
    save('test.mat','input')
    return
end
```

And if you want to use same data structure you can use :

```
data.input=1:10;
save('test.mat','-struct','data')
```